# Filtering Post Content (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, post

I am involved in a web project under Wordpress and I need if you could help me with the following issue. In each one of the posts of the web there is an embedded video (usually from Youtube), through the following shortcode:

```
[video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYZxmYP7QOo"]
```

In the page where these post are shown, below the video, there are comments from the different users of the website, the title of the video, link to the social networks of author, etc ...).

Additionally, I created a page where the user who is logged on the web, can see the entire list of videos that he has uploaded. The question is now, when this page shows the user information, all the content of the post is shown too (including, p.e, comments). I would like that only the video and its title were shown (without comments or any other information). The code written up to now is the following one:

```
// tipo POSTS
$the_args['post_type']='post';
$the_query = new WP_Query($the_args);
?>
<?php if ($the_query-> have_posts ()) :?>
<h2>posts</h2>
<ul>
    <?php while ($the_query-> have_posts ()) : $the_query-> the_post();
      the_content();
    php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Question:**

How can I filter `the content()`? I understand that it should be using the function `add_filter ()`, but I do not get to know the specify code to do it.

Regards

Comment: Its very unclear what you're asking. Can you give specific details of what you are trying to do - for example, where are these comments etc coming from? Are you sure they in the post content, and are not just standard comments for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the shortcode, you can create a [custom field for the video](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/oembed/), then filter the output like below

```
   <?php while ($the_query-> have_posts ()) : $the_query-> the_post();
      the_title();
      the_field('video');
    php endwhile; ?>
```